Why does Newton-Raphson require a Convex Function to work?
Here is the Newton-Raphson optimization algorithm:
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f'(x_k)}{f''(x_k)}$$
For any Convex Function, the Newton-Raphson optimization algorithm is supposed to result in the following after an infinite number of iterations:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (f(x_n) - f(x^*)) = 0$$
I am trying to understand why this can only happen for a Convex Function.
Suppose I start with some convex function $h(x)$. We know that a convex function has the following properties:

$h''(x) > 0$ for all $x$ (positive second derivative)
It has a unique global minimum

Let's say the minimum of $h(x)$ occurs at $x^*$. As $k \to \infty$:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = x^*$$
$$h'(x^*) = 0$$
$$h''(x^*) > 0$$
To begin, imagine the Newton-Raphson algorithm being evaluated at some point $x_k$. Now, we subtract $x^*$ from both sides. This is allowed because we do it on both sides.
$$x_{k+1} - x^* = (x_k - x^*) - \frac{h'(x_k)}{h''(x_k)}$$
Since its a derivative at the true minimum, $h'(x^*) = 0$, so we can also subtract it as a formality:
$$= (x_k - x^*) - \frac{h'(x_k) - h'(x^*)}{h''(x_k)}$$

I think this is where we need to use the Mean Value Theorem (MVT). It states that for a function $f(x)$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that:
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$$
Applying this to $h'(x)$ on the interval $[x^*, x_k]$, we get (note, in MVT we compare a first derivative to the original function ... here, we are comparing the second derivative to the first derivative):
$$h''(\xi) = \frac{h'(x_k) - h'(x^*)}{x_k - x^*}$$
where $\xi$ is some point between $x^*$ and $x_k$. This represents the $c$ term in the MVT.
Rearranging this MVT equation:
$$h'(x_k) - h'(x^*) = h''(\xi)(x_k - x^*)$$
This is where we had left off prior (On the RHS, the numerator of the second term equals the LHS of the MVT equation):
$$x_{k+1} - x^* = (x_k - x^*) - \frac{h'(x_k) - h'(x^*)}{h''(x_k)}$$
Now, we use our insights from the MVT:
$$x_{k+1} - x^* = (x_k - x^*) - \frac{h''(\xi)(x_k - x^*)}{h''(x_k)}$$
Factoring out $(x_k - x^*)$:
$$x_{k+1} - x^* = (x_k - x^*)\left(1 - \frac{h''(\xi)}{h''(x_k)}\right)$$
The logic here is a bit shaky for me. As $k \to \infty$, we expect $x_k \to x^*$. This means $\xi \to x^*$ as well, since $\xi$ is between $x_k$ and $x^*$. Therefore, in the limit:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} (x_{k+1} - x^*) = \lim_{k \to \infty} (x_k - x^*)\left(1 - \frac{h''(x^*)}{h''(x^*)}\right)$$
Simplifying:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} (x_{k+1} - x^*) = \lim_{k \to \infty} (x_k - x^*)(1 - 1) = 0$$
This shows that as $k \to \infty$, the distance between $x_{k+1}$ and $x^*$ approaches zero, demonstrating convergence of the Newton-Raphson method for convex functions.
Can a similar argument be made to show that the Newton-Raphson is not guaranteed to achieve this result on a non-convex function?

You are dividing by $h''(x_k)$. If this is zero, say, you are in trouble. You can perhaps try to also think geometrically (draw graphs) and think about how the algorithm can fail.

This section of the Wikipedia article on Newton's method has various conditions for convergence:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Analysis

Who says it "can only happen for a Convex Function"? That would be difficult to prove, since it's not literally true. But later you write "not guaranteed" ... now that's the right way to say it. All you need for that is one counterexample.

I never had to read such a complicated piece on Newton-Raphson. Even the start is confusing: do you want to search for a root of $f'$ or of $f$ ? This might even answer the question in the title.

@YvesDaoust I agree. Wanted OP to clarify that. When $f$ is strictly convex then $f'$ is increasing and has at most one root (stationary point of $f$). This is more than sufficient but not necessary for NR to converge on  $f',.$

It's also worth studying the behaviour of$$\frac{x_{k+1}-x^\ast}{(x_k-x^\ast)^2}.$$

From NR Optimization algorithm equation,
$$\operatorname{sgn}(f''(x_k))=\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(f'(x_k))}{\operatorname{sgn}(x_k-x_{k+1})}=\color{red}{+}1$$
because around minumum $x^*$, it must happen that $\operatorname{sgn}(f'(x_k))=\operatorname{sgn}(x_k-x_{k+1})$. So, we need convexity.
Example: For $=x^{\frac23}$ which is not convex, the algorithm gives $x_{k+1}=4x_k$ which diverges.

The function $(x^{2/3})'=2x^{-1/3}/3$ has no root and that is why the algorithm can never ever converge. What has that to do with convexity? The function $x^2+1$ is convex and has no root either.

But $(x^2+1)'=2x$ has a root. @Kurt

Sorry, bad example. :) I wanted to demonstrate that the convexity of $f$  is not needed for a root of $f',.$ Such an example is trivially the concave function $-x^2,.$

@KurtG. I considered the minimum you considered the maximum.

In that case I agree.
